# cloudfront redirecting to origin instead of aliasing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ssl, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using a Cloudfront distribution as a proxy for my Heroku server. Why? for [these](http://ksylvest.com/posts/2014-05-06/setup-free-ish-ssl-tls-on-heroku-for-ruby-on-rails-or-any-other-framework) purposes.

Anyway, my app has a force ssl rule on it. When I go to my cloudfront url, the origin being my heroku app url, i'm getting a 301 redirect to the origin, instead of serving as an alias.

Some stuff i did:

At first i had an error saying `"request could not be satisfied"`, so  I changed the origin protocol policy to HTTP Only.

Then, I had a redirect loop, so after researching I found out it was caused by the host header being passed in, so i removed forwarding headers.

Now i'm getting this 301 redirect.How can i stop it? What configurations should i look at?

Appreaciate any ideas. Happy to provide any additional information.

Comment: Glad my answer helped! Just as an FYI, I stopped using CloudFront after a few days of testing as it has really poor performance. I'm trying out Fastly right now and it's *very* good in the U.S. (but bad overseas).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just started using CloudFront yesterday and was having the exact same issue. I found the answer below and realized my non-www to www redirect was causing the problem:

> I was redirecting from domain.com to www.domain.com and CloudFront was
>   caching and returning that redirect. You would probably see the same
>   thing with an http/https redirect.
>
> If you're doing an HTTP -> HTTPS redirect, you have two options: You
>   can either serve the assets to CloudFront as HTTP or make CloudFront
>   request them as HTTPS. To do the latter, you would need to configure
>   your CloudFront origin to "Match Viewer." That means that if the
>   viewer is using HTTPS, CloudFront will also. If the user is using
>   HTTP, CloudFront would request in HTTP, return the HTTPS redirect it
>   received from your server, and the client would then re-issue the
>   request as HTTPS.
>
> In our case, the assets themselves do not need to be protected
>   in-flight. It is only important that they are served from CloudFront
>   as HTTPS so the user's browser is seeing all HTTPS content. So, in our
>   case, it is not necessary to serve the assets to CloudFront as HTTPS.
>   Regardless of how it fetches the content from our server, CloudFront
>   will match the viewer's protocol when it responds.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571467/1101095

One thing you could try is removing any rewrite rules from your .htaccess file temporarily, then try loading a new file through CloudFront. Try a new file each time, because CloudFront caches the responses it gets (whether it's the file or not).

Comment: Not sure how it helps.