# How to stop domain redirects when using a CloudFront domain as the custom origin at Lambda@Edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I want to use different origins according to the relative paths of my website.

My root domain is **example.com** and it should be served with **example01.cloudfront.net**
and **example.com/pathxx/** should be served with **example02.cloudfront.net**.
These two CloudFront distributions are linked to two s3 buckets with static sites.

I have mapped the *example.com* to another CloudFront distribution.
Following is the code I'm using at the Lambda@Edge on that Cloudfront distribution's origin-request trigger.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    let domain = "";
    if (request.uri.match(/\/pathxx\//)) {
      domain = "example02.cloudfront.net";
      request.uri = request.uri.replace(/\/pathxx\//,"/");
    } else {
      domain = "example01.cloudfront.net";
    }

    request.origin = {
          custom: {
            domainName: domain,
            port: 80,
            protocol: "http",
            path: "",
            sslProtocols: ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1"],
            readTimeout: 5,
            keepaliveTimeout: 5,
            customHeaders: {}
          }
    };
    
    request.headers["host"] = [{ key: "host", value: domain }];
    callback(null, request);
};
```

When I used this code and enter *example.com* on the browser then it redirects to the *example01.cloudfront.net*
and *example.com/pathxx* redirects to the *example02.cloudfront.net* by receiving 301 status codes.

But if I change the CloudFront origins to their s3 bucket URLs then this redirection doesn't occur and I will see my example.com domain always as I'm expecting and I will not receive any 301 codes which causes redirects.

```
...
    if (request.uri.match(/\/pathxx\//)) {
      domain = "example02.s3.amazonaws.com";
      request.uri = request.uri.replace(/\/pathxx\//,"/");
    } else {
      domain = "example01.s3.amazonaws.com";
    }
...
```

**Is that means we can't use CloudFront distribution domains as custom origins??**

Due to caching issues, I must use CloudFront domains for the custom origins therefore I cannot use s3 bucket URLs. This is a limitation on my project's architecture and also using CloudFront domains meant to achieve pre-caching also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503322/cloudfront-distribution-with-custom-origin-redirects-request/22571467#2257146):

CloudFront seems to be going through the HTTP to HTTPS redirection when it tries to use the CloudFront origins and as a result my domain changes on the browser.

So, I did change my two CloudFront distributions (example01.cloudfront.net and example02.cloudfront.net) to use "**HTTP and HTTPS**" option for the **Viewer Protocol Policy** of the origin on the Behaviors tab. So they will not redirect to HTPPS forcefully anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A single Cloudfront distribution can be configured to serve content from multiple origins (e.g. 2 different S3 buckets). So you can (without using Lambda at all) have:

#### Route53

- example.com -> CloudFront distrubtion A

#### Cloudfront (distribution A)

- example.com/* -> origin s3-bucket-1
- example.com/pathx/ -> origin s3-bucket-2

See [this guide](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-route-to-multiple-origins-with-cloudfront/) for a walkthrough (with API Gateway + S3).

Comment: Yeah, this approach also should work but we finalized our approach on a single Cloudfront distribution which talks to a reverse proxy(Nginx) to select the correct s3 origin as per the requested path. As you mentioned we understood that we do not need multiple CloudFront distributions to do the caching as well because we can invalidate a single cached path and still keep the cashed content on the other paths.